# MOSFET Switching without gate voltage / LED Strip

Tags: led, mosfet, raspberry-pi

I have ordered logic-level MOSFETS of the type IRLZ34N (for the sake of working on a Raspberry Pi) but I have problems in Wiring it up. 
I have so far connected:

- +12 to the +12v lane of the switch
- FET Drain to the blue color of the switch
- FET Source to the negative terminal of the lab PSU
- FET Gate to GPIO pin

My setup is comparable to this diagram:
[image]
Apart from me having only wired one color, not three and not using TIP120 but IRLZ34N. Same pinout (Gate/Drain/Source and Base/Collector/Emitter, read from front left to right)

However, the LED strip just lights up blue right away. Even with the raspberry pi turned off. Or the Gate Wire removed from the jumper cable (i.e. 100% sure that there is no voltage on gate)

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: double check your fets pinou and exchange the blue one with the one for green.

Comment: Connect the gate to ground. Does it turn off? "Disconnected" is not the same as "zero volts".

Comment: Connecting gate to the PSUs ground does indeed turn the FET off.

Comment: How about a circuit diagram and not a cartoon that shows TIP120 Darlington BJTs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your GPIO pins are not configured to output low, they'll be in an undefined state. A FET's gate takes effectively 0 input current, so the voltage on the gate will fluctuate arbitrarily, and may well lead to it being biased 'on'.

Add pulldown resistors to your circuit so that the switches default to off unless being driven by the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: You're helping me out the second time already Mister Johnson, thank you heaps! What resistor value should I use and where should it be added? Adding a 10k between Gate and GPIO did not yet change anything.

Comment: Other way round: connect the gate directly (or via a small resistor of a few hundred ohms), and put the 10k between gate and ground. As Nick says, it picks a voltage from stray capacitance, the human body, static in the air, and passing radio waves.

Comment: What pjc50 said!

Comment: Between Gate and Ground means from the FETs Gate pin to the PSUs ground, correct?

Comment: @RobinHeller Correct.

Comment: 10k seems to high a value: I couldn't get the MOSFET to switch at all (apart from connecting gate to the psu) , which somehow seems very strange to me since pull-up values are normally not that hard to pick, are they?

Comment: @RobinHeller Can you update your schematic to show where you connected it? To be clear, there should be no resistor between the gate and the RPi pin, and a pull down resistor between the gate and the ground rail.

Comment: Which ground rail was I supposed to connect it to? I have a ground rail available on the RPi and one from my PSU (lab PSU with positive/negative/ground terminal)

Comment: Your PSU negative terminal must be connected to the RPi's ground terminal.

Comment: As Peter says, all your grounds must be connected together - otherwise, you don't have a circuit.

Comment: I keep shortening and defecting my mosfets, sometimes randomly by connecting the RPi To the circuit. Will adding pull down resistor help?

Comment: For anyone searching how to add resistor from gate to ground: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wd6NzCY3NgI